# Override bootstrap-table checked row background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery bootstrap-table plugin and I need to change the color of the checked row and restore the original color when unchecked. This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1yvr1kun/4/ shows how to do this when the event is a click. I have tried to implement the idea on a check event but the checked rows do not get highlighted in the set color. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amotha/e3nk137y/9186/ How can I make the change happen on the checked rows and reverse when unchecked?

HTML:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table"
       data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       data-single-select="false">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        $('.success').removeClass('success');
        $($element).addClass('success');
});
```

CSS:

```
.success td{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: If i were you i would simply overwrite the .selected calss which is given to the selected tr instead of creating your own class which basically does the same.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/daswagpanda/e3nk137y/9195/

Comment: @luca that works quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change class name on css

```
.success td{
    background-color:red !important;
}

.selected td{
    background-color:#b1d54f !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9196/